# Store the data in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to store a data to the mysql database but if i press the submit button it display the php page.

form:

```
<div id="test">
<form action="demo.php"  method="post">
please enter the number(1 to 100) : <input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

demo.php

```
<?php
$value=$_POST['value'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "clock";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO input  VALUES (".$_POST['value'].")";

if ($conn->query($input) == TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You are in danger that mean of SQL Injection.
But for your answer, your query will be, `$input = "INSERT INTO input (value) VALUES ('".$value."')";`
Don't use `Mysql` keyword as your table name. Use another.

Comment: Raw php code is showing is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$input` with `$sql` in the `if` statement:

**From**

```
if ($conn->query($input) == TRUE) {
```

**To**

```
if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
```

**Note:** Since you are storing `$_POST['value']` in `$value`, you don't need to use `$_POST['value']` in the query, instead make use of `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one correction:

Change

`if ($conn->query($input) == TRUE) {`

To:

`if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {`

Along with that, following are suggestions:

$sql = "INSERT INTO input  VALUES (".$_POST['value'].")";

This query is OK, is value of `$_POST['value']` is integer, but, for strings, it will create SQL Syntax Error.

Please correct this to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO input  VALUES ('".$_POST['value']."')";
```

Observe, enclosed semi colon.

2) You are inserting only one field value and not specifying fields. This means you table has only field. Normally we do not have tables with only one field.

Please specify field names:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO input (field_one)  VALUES (".$_POST['value'].")";
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** Add name attribute to submit button `name="submit"`

```
<input name="submit" type="submit">
```

**2nd :** use `isset` like this `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //rest of code here }`

**3rd :** Try to use `prepared statement or pdo` to avoid `sql injection`

**demo.php**

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "*****";
    $dbname = "clock";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO input(value) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['value']);

       //The argument may be one of four types:

            //i - integer
            //d - double
            //s - string
            //b - BLOB
            //change it by respectively

        if ($stmt->execute() == TRUE && $stmt->affected_rows>0) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: <br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Get values like this*

```
  $value=$_REQUEST['value'];
```

*change the query to*

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO input  VALUES ('$value')";
```